# my android emulator not showing my app

Tags: android, emulation

When I first tried to run my application, it went fine, but when I added a splash class. It messed things up.

Here's my android manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.fps.iHealthFirst"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SPLASH" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".IHealthFirstActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_ihealth_first" >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.IHEALTHFIRSTACTIVITY" />
    </activity>

</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".IHealthFirstActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_ihealth_first">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: HI, when I added intent-filter in it throws (exported activity does not require permission)

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes If so just add android:exported="false", see updated answer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13742/discussion-between-k-anas-and-betty-barnes)

Comment: Hi I already and actually saw my app but every time I click my app it stops unexpectedly.

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes can you post your logcat error, also let's talk in chat you can click the link aove

Answer (score 0):

in below code you added `<action/>` without `<intent-filter>`, try adding intent filter in it.

```
<activity
    android:name=".IHealthFirstActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_ihealth_first" >
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.IHEALTHFIRSTACTIVITY" />
</activity>
```

BTW, Why you need to add custom Action in Activity declaration!! or You can also try after removing action tag if not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
<activity
        android:name=".Splash" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
<activity android:name=".IHealthFirstActivity"
android:label="@string/title_activity_ihealth_first"></activity>
```